# Undo changes after merged pull request

Tags: git, merge, pull-request

I have a branch development. I created a new branch X from it, and made some changes, then I created a new branch from X, branch Y, and in this branch I made big refactor of `names of variables`, like 30 files changed. After refactor I created pull request from branch Y to X, and merged it. Then i made some changes on branch X and then i created pull request and merged branch X to development. Can i undo branch Y, with these 30 files changed with refactor of names in it? If yes, how can I do it?

Demonstration:

[image: Demonstration picture]

Comment: Are you saying you renamed 30 _files_, or you renamed some variables inside 30 files?

Comment: Second option, I renamed some variables inside 30 files.

Answer (score 2):

You could try reverting the commit in `Y` in which you did the renaming:

```
git revert <SHA-1 of Y commit
```

This should completely undo everything which happened in that Y commit, including the variable renaming.

To find the commit hash which you want to revert in `development`, one simple option would be to just use `git log`, which will show you a list of commits from most recent to earlier.

Comment: And then what? After I revert changes on branch Y, then I will have some changes to commit, I make commit and push it, and then merge it into branch X and then from branch X to development?

Comment: Nope.  When you `git revert` that commit you add a _new_ commit which is sort of the mirror image of the commit you made to `Y` which changed all the variable names.

Comment: So when I will do git revert, then I get a new commit, which I should push into the development, and this will revert all changes from branch Y that was merged into branch X and then development? Taking everything into account, after these changes I will have branch development with reverted refactor of renamed variables? And if I changed same files on development and in branch Y, may there be some conflicts?

Comment: Yes you could get conflicts when reverting.  Just resolve them then push `development` to the remote.